# Which Security provided by pentaho in S3 output any encryption?

Tags: pentaho-spoon

I am using Pentaho, and used s3 output step to put the file in S3 bucket but I want to know which in-transit security is provided by pentaho and how to apply AES encryption in Pentaho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pentaho can encrypt only your password with aes currently. 
You can use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html 
for serverside encryption. 
For any transit/client side encryption I`d suggest you to write your own plugin with extending functionality of existing s3 output.

Or submit ticket for desired functioanality at http://jira.pentaho.com .

Comment: I check Pentaho is not using any encryption but Using Spring security that's be safe.